# Magento2: product page returns error

Tags: magento2, attributes, catalog

With no apparent reason, product pages do not show for me anymore.
Error text:

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /path/to/project/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/AbstractSource.php on line 74
```

I tried to xdebug it, here is what I found. Error happens in the following method of AbstractSource.php class:

```
public function getOptionText($value)
{
    $options = $this->getAllOptions();
    // Fixed for tax_class_id and custom_design
    if (sizeof($options) > 0) {
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if (isset($option['value']) && $option['value'] == $value) {
                return isset($option['label']) ? $option['label'] : $option['value'];
            }
        }
    }
    // Error here
    if (isset($options[$value])) {
        return $options[$value];
    }
    return false;
}
```

The error occurs because $value is an array:
    `$value = array("is_in_stock" => true, "qty" => 1);` whereas Magento expects a scalar that can be used as array key.

All the trouble is caused by product attribute with code `quantity_and_stock_status` - but it is not my custom attribute, it comes out of the box, and I did not change any of its settings.

I reinstalled my entire app, still got the same result.

So it looks to me that it's a Magento internal bug - but it used to work fine, I did not update codebase in any way. What could be the reason that this bug occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you might have the attribute "quantity_and_stock_status" marked as **"Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront"** on the admin panel.

The problem is that  on line 74:

`if (isset($options[$value])) {`

**$value should not be an array**, but for the stock attribute it is an array, therefore this line crashes.

You either switch it back to Non-visible on Catalog Pages, or plugin this method to validate that $value is not an array.

Will be submiting this on on github.

Comment: Sorry, I can neither confirm nor deny your solution is working. I do not have access to that project code anymore

Comment: For further users reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7080